# How can I make overflowing on top side to make reversed scrolling work?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The following code cannot be scrolled as `overflow: auto` does not allow overflowing to top side. Is there still a way to allow scrolling here **with pure css**, **without additional container divs?**

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.container div {
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
It seems this is browser bug.

Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1042151

Edge UserVoice: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/10461201-support-reverse-scrolling-when-justify-content-fl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse` (*multi-line*) where in it doesn't allow scrolling at all.

For your particular use-case (*fixed width with one item across*), you could use `flex-direction` with `column-reverse` and achieve the same result that you are intending to.

**Snippet:**

```css
.container {
    display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse;
    height: 150px; width: 150px;
    overflow: auto; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.container div {
    min-width: 100px; min-height: 100px; margin: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); color: #fff;
}
.container div:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #33a; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This beautifully works on Chrome but not on Firefox and Edge. Unfortunately it must work on Edge. Do you have any workaround?

Comment: @KagamiSaschaRosylight: Whoops! Yes, FF seems to have many problems with flex. Here is one bug report which is pending since long -- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=570036

Comment: It seems I have to file a new bug if there is no other solution.

Comment: A related bug says this is now in spec and browsers should work as Chrome does: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1042151

Comment: @KagamiSaschaRosylight: Yes that looks like a more accurate bug report. But the status is not closed and there is no progress on the implementation. You could add your test-case over there and wait for a closure.

Comment: Good suggestion, I just added one :D